# WPF: Dynamically loading images from the current assembly

Tags: wpf, image

This is my XAML

```
<Image Name="StatusImage" Source="/Foo.Bar.Sam;component/Images/YellowDot.png" Stretch="Fill" MaxWidth="12" MaxHeight="12">
```

Using VB or C#, how would I change the `Image` to RedDot or GreenDot?

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/397117/wpf-image-dynamically-changing-image-source-during-runtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

code taken from [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397117/wpf-image-dynamically-changing-image-source-during-runtime)

```
string strUri2 = String.Format(@"pack://application:,,,/MyAseemby;component/resources/main titles/{0}", CurrenSelection.TitleImage);
imgTitle.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(strUri2));
```

Comment: If you find a duplicate question, then you should comment and vote to close rather than posting an answer.

Comment: thanks for the tip. After reviewing the other q, I don't think its a duplicate question. The other question was about image resizing.