# Error in Visual Studio 2010 designer when binding using StringFormat

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, data-binding, string-formatting

I'm using Silverlight and in my xaml I try to bind an Image source with StringFormat like the example in [WPF Image Dynamically changing Image source during runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397117/wpf-image-dynamically-changing-image-source-during-runtime)

But when I add '&amp;' in my URL there is an error saying:
System.FormatException was thrown on "ProductView.xaml": Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

This is my Image tag i xaml:

```
<Image Width="100" Height="100" Source="{Binding Image.ResourceFileId, StringFormat='http://URL/images?id={0}&amp;format=thumbnail'}" />
```

There is no error when removing the '&amp;'-part, and the application compiles and runs both with and without the '&amp;'-part. It is only an error in the designer, but the effect is that IntelliSense no longer seems to work when this error is "active".

Does anyone have an explanation for this?

Answer (score 1):

I think the braces are what is giving you a problem. It should look like this instead:

```
StringFormat='http://URL/images?id=\{0\}&amp;format=thumbnail'
```