# WPF C# Image Source

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In XAML, I learned to specify image source with below code:

```
<Image Source="/WaivePadBankAnim;component/Images/Consumer/search_button_full.png" />
```

How would I do it in C# .cs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Image image = new Image();
image.UriSource = new Uri("/WaivePadBankAnim;component/Images/Consumer/search_button_full.png")
```

[Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397117/wpf-image-dynamically-changing-image-source-during-runtime)

[Adding WPF Controls Progrrammatically](http://arcanecode.com/2007/09/07/adding-wpf-controls-progrrammatically/)

Answer (score 1):

M working on Windows phone 8 and i used this.

OrderImage1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("///Assets/images/order_bread.png"));

Answer (score 0):

```
Image img = new Image();
img.Source = new Uri("<your path here>");
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

please check this

just use a class "ImageSourceConverter"

```
img1.Source = (ImageSource)new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFromString("/Assets/check.png");
```